# WooCommerce | Customer's total spend on completed orders in a given time period

Tags: woocommerce

The code below is said to give the total spent spent over 30 days (if I'm not mistaken). But in my test, it calculates for the current month. How can I not update this code for last 6 months(180 days). The important thing is to be able to easily change the coverage day and make the calculation for the completed orders. Thanks.
Code resource:https://github.com/anaymark/woocommerce-monthly-spent-by-user/blob/master/total-spent-month-by-user.php

```
function total_spent_for_user_30days( $user_id=null ) {
    if ( empty($user_id) ){
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    }
    $today_year = date( 'Y' );
    $today_month = date( 'm' );
    $day = date( 'd' );
    if ($today_month == '01') {
        $month = '12';
        $year = $today_year - 1;
    } else{
        $month = $today_month - 1;
        $month = sprintf("%02d", $month);
        $year = $today_year - 1;
    }
    // ORDERS FOR LAST 30 DAYS (Time calculations)
    $now = strtotime('now');
    $gap_days = 30;
    $gap_days_in_seconds = 60*60*24*$gap_days;
    $gap_time = $now - $gap_days_in_seconds;
    $args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
        'post_status' => array( 'wc-completed' ),
        // all posts
        'numberposts' => -1,
        // for current user id
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => $user_id,
        'date_query' => array(
            //orders published on last 30 days
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'year' => $today_year,
                'month' => $today_month,
            ),
            array(
                'year' => $year,
                'month' => $month,
            ),
        ),
    );
    // GET ALL ORDERS
    $customer_orders = get_posts( $args );
    $count = 0;
    $total = 0;
    $no_orders_message = __('No orders this month.', 'mytheme');
    if (!empty($customer_orders)) {
        $customer_orders_date = array();
        foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ){
            $customer_order_date = strtotime($customer_order->post_date);
            // PAST 30 DAYS
            if ( $customer_order_date > $gap_time ) {
                $customer_order_date;
                $order = new WC_Order( $customer_order->ID );
                $order_items = $order->get_items();
                $total += $order->get_total();
                // Going through each current customer items in the order
                foreach ( $order_items as $order_item ){
                   $count++;
                }
            }
        }
        $monthly_spent_by_user =  floatval( preg_replace( '#[^\d.]#', '', $total, $count ) );
        
        return $monthly_spent_by_user;
        
    } else {
        return $no_orders_message;         
    }
}

add_shortcode( 'spent-last-month', 'total_spent_for_user_30days' );
```

Comment: Woo have its own query use that instead - https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query

Comment: @MartinMirchev thank you.  I guess it's okay.